# Storing data in a list without losing them (C#)

Tags: c#, list, max, min

Guys, I'm creating a program in C# that will read Income and Outgo, both provided by the user, and will store them in 2 lists. When requested, the program must show the minimum and maximum values stored inside the lists. The `Income` and `Outgo` values can be added as many times as the user wants, and every time a value is added, the program go back to the menu which have 3 options: add new income, add new outgo and show min/max values so far. The problem is, every time I try to show the min/max values, the program says to me: `"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'`, so I think no values are being stored in the lists. Can someone help? Thank you!

```
class Class2
{
    List<double> income = new List<double>();
    List<double> outgo = new List<double>();
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();

   public void FunctionIncome()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Income: ");
        income.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
        c1.options();
    }

    public void FunctionOutgo()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Outgo: ");
        outgo.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
        c1.options();
    }

    public void functionMinMax()
    {
            double minI = income.Min();
            double maxI = income.Max();
            double minO = outgo.Min();
            double maxO = outgo.Max();

            Console.WriteLine($"Minimum income: {minI}\nMaximum income: {maxI}\nMinimum outgo: {minO}\nMaximum outgo: {maxO}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            c1.options();
    }
```

Comment: where do you call these functions? `FunctionIncome`, `FunctionOutgo` etc..

Comment: Make sure your program works only with **one and the same** object instance of `Class2`. Make sure that your program is not working with two or more instances of Class2 by accident.

Comment: `Class1` and `Class2` are ridiculously terrible names for classes. Also where is `Class1`'s definition? Think about how to refactor your program so every statement is only written once.

Comment: Did you try static lists?

Answer (score 0):

a class represents the structure of objects but was not supposed to store actual data in long term usage and to be used like database , in ur case every object u will create of class 2 will have a new empty list of doubles.

u might think the solution is to have only one fixed instance of the class , a static class or singleton , that might work , still u will lose all of ur data if the process has been killed or u exit the application , and it's not a best practice by all means

in cases like that u will need some where to store the data in it for long term usage like a database , external xml files